# Toggle one div who use same class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, toggle

I'm  trying to use some divs with same class but my goal is to toggle on click only one div from them at the time. I mean that when I click on "+" I would like to show only where I click and the all of them in same time, so I tried some things like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/X7p28/) but no luck, nothing work.

---

UPDATE

I've updated the code so thanks you for your help it works perfectly.

But now I don't know why, my content visible before to click on the "+" is bigger than my card width, contrary to the content visible when I click on the "+". Can someone explain me why my content does not fit perfectly with my card ? You can click on the "+" and "-" to see the difference.

```js
 $(function() {
  $(".click-me").each(function() {
    $(this).flip({
      axis: "y",
      reverse: true,
      trigger: "click",
      speed: '800',
      front: $(this).siblings('.my-front-card'),
      back: $(this).siblings('.my-back-card'),
      autoSize: false
    });
  });
});


$(".click-me").click(function() {
  $(this).html($(".click-me").html() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
});
```

```css
a {
color: white;
}

.card-container {
width: 100%;
}

.card {
max-width: 500px;
width: 31.3%;
margin: 0 1%;
min-height: 260px;
padding: 40px 40px 20px 40px;
border-radius: 20px;
background: black;
color: white;
float: left;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #ccc;
}

.card-container .card {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
.my-front-card, .my-back-card {
max-width: 420px;
width: 100%; 
min-height: 260px;
}
  
.click-me {
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
text-align: right;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.card {
width: auto;
float: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>



    <div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">

  <div class="my-front-card">
    Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="my-back-card">
  <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
  Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor turpis.
  </div> 
  
  
  <div class="click-me">+</div>

</div>



<div class="card">

  <div class="my-front-card">
    Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="my-back-card">
  <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
  Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor turpis.
  </div> 
  
  
  <div class="click-me">+</div>

</div>





<div class="card">

  <div class="my-front-card">
    Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="my-back-card">
  <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
  Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor turpis.
  </div> 
  
  
  <div class="click-me">+</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery lookup `$(".click-me")` collects more than one element (3 here).

So you need to instanciate the `.flip()` on each of them separately. Additionnaly, you need to specify the `front` and `back` elements more specifically, using `$(this).siblings()` to make sure there is only one element looked up.

I removed the `ChangeText()` inline onclick attribute because it was undefined...

```js
$(function() {
  $(".click-me").each(function() {
    $(this).flip({
      axis: "y",
      reverse: true,
      trigger: "click",
      speed: '800',
      front: $(this).siblings('.my-front-card'),
      back: $(this).siblings('.my-back-card'),
      autoSize: false
    });
  });
});


$(".click-me").click(function() {
  $(this).html($(".click-me").html() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
});
```

```css
.card {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 60px;
  padding: 40px 40px 20px 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: grey;
}

.my-front-card,
.my-back-card {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 60px;
}

.click-me {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>



<div class="card">


  <div class="my-front-card">
    Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
  </div>


  <div class="my-back-card">
    <a href="http://google.com">link</a> Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor
    turpis.
  </div>


  <div class="click-me">+</div>


</div>












<div class="card">


  <div class="my-front-card">
    Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
  </div>


  <div class="my-back-card">
    <a href="http://google.com">link</a> Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor
    turpis.
  </div>


  <div class="click-me">+</div>


</div>













<div class="card">


  <div class="my-front-card">
    Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
  </div>


  <div class="my-back-card">
    <a href="http://google.com">link</a> Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor
    turpis.
  </div>


  <div class="click-me">+</div>


</div>
```

Comment: easiest answer here

Comment: It works perfectly thanks but can you please read the section update of my post, may be I missed something that I can't solve ? @Louys

Comment: I tried to run you snippet and I do not see the issue. Now that looks like another question. You should post that new issue on a new question and make sure it is reproduced in the code snippet.

Comment: when you open the code snipped in fullscreen you can see that when you resize the content inside does not fit very well, I'm talking about the front content only. I mean when cards are too small, the content does not fit perfectly, it's bigger than the card.

Answer (score 0):

your `front` and `back` hold all elments with the class `.my-front-card` and `.my-back-card` in an array. In order to flip only the cards of the element clicked, you need to select them like so

```
$(this).closest('.card).find('.my-front-card')
```

In order to do that you need to apply the "flip" to each element individually :

```
$.each($(".click-me"), function() {
    $(this).flip({
        ...
        front: $(this).closest('.card).find('.my-front-card'), 
         
        ...
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $.each($(".click-me"), function() {
    $(this).flip({
        axis: "y",
        reverse: true,
        trigger: "click",
        speed: '800',
        front: $(this).closest('.card').find('.my-front-card'),
        back: $(this).closest('.card').find('.my-back-card'),
        autoSize: false
      });
  });
      
});
    
    
$(".click-me").click(function(){
   $(".click-me").html($(".click-me").html() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
});
```

```css
.card {
max-width: 500px;
min-height: 60px;
padding: 40px 40px 20px 40px;
border-radius: 20px;
background: grey;
}
      
.my-front-card, .my-back-card {
max-width: 500px;
min-height: 60px;
}
      
.click-me {
cursor: pointer;
text-align: right;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>



<div class="card">


  <div class="my-front-card">
    Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
  </div>
  
      
  <div class="my-back-card">
  <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
  Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor turpis.
  </div> 
      
      
  <div class="click-me">+</div>
   
   
</div>












<div class="card">


  <div class="my-front-card">
    Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
  </div>
  
      
  <div class="my-back-card">
  <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
  Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor turpis.
  </div> 
      
      
  <div onclick="ChangeText()"  class="click-me">+</div>
   
   
</div>













<div class="card">


  <div class="my-front-card">
    Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
  </div>
  
      
  <div class="my-back-card">
  <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
  Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor turpis.
  </div> 
      
      
  <div onclick="ChangeText()"  class="click-me">+</div>
   
   
</div>
```